# unknown character set index for field '255' received from server

Tags: mysql

The version of MySQL is 8.0.19, and I set the version of MySQL in the pom as 8.0.19. However, it doesn't work. I have looked for an answer to this problem in Google for a day, but none of them worked. Who can help me?

Here is jdbc in my code:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeesystemdb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;useSSL=false"
```

Here is dependency of `mysql-connector-java` in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of this problem is changing the version of mysql and the versionsl setting of mysql-connector in pom.xml to 5.1.40